# How to get all users' steam id

Tags: api, steam, steam-web-api, steamworks-api

I'm trying to get all users' Steam id on Steam. I've tried to use steam API, but there's no method to find every player on steam.

How can I get all the players IDs on steam ?

Answer (score 0):

I think Steam will not allow to fetch all Users with one command. To transfer this big data within one or two function calls will let the server go in their knees. On the other side the user have to set their profiel `public` that you can search them. But you can fetch the Steam users about the friendlist and if the friends profile is`public`then you can fetch their friends and so on.